# How to fix width of Search box in react-select dropdown component?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select dropdown component in my react application. i found one weird issue that when user start typing for searching an item in react-select dropdown, search textbox gets stretch and its not a fixed with dropdown list.

Please see below image.
How can i fix the search textbox width to react-select width?

[image]

Comment: you can use react-toolbox select

Comment: have you tried doing it with css?

Comment: Yes, i tried with giving width to parent div of React-select but still no luck

Answer (score 10):

Just set

```
autosize={false}
```

on the component.

Comment: This solution isn't working in v3.0.3. I am facing the same problem as OP. Would appreciate inputs to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I inspected browser and found out that if I set width to 82%, my problem will be solved. So I added that inside "Select" tag and it works

```
  <Select

      value={this.state.passwordExpire}
      onChange={this.updatepasswordExpire.bind(this)}
      options={optionsDays}
      style={{width: '82%'}}  
 />
```

Comment: Does absolutely nothing for me...It's been over an hour....All I want........is to shrink the width....of my react-select........................oh my god..... EDIT: Well I didn't want to wrap the `<Select>` in a `<div>` to shrink the width but that's what I ended up doing...not worth my time to do it "the right way" anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const customStyles={
      // control represent the select component
        control: (provided)=>({
          ...provided,
          width:'100px'
       })
     }
    <Select
      options={options}
      styles={customStyles}
    ></Select>
```

This method is stated in react-select documentation. You can adjust select width as per your wish.

Comment: I think you want to use `container` instead of `control`, so that the drop-down menu is the same width as the control. Otherwise, it defaults to the width of the select's parent. Also, spreading `provided` is critical. I didn't include it at first and things went haywire.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this css.

```
.Select-input {  
  position: absolute !important; 
  width: calc(~'100% - 0px');
}

.Select-value-label {
  display: none !important;
}

.Select-value {
  position: relative !important;
}

.Select-menu-outer {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

.Select-option {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.Select-control {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: `!important` in CSS is the red flag for me. It means something went completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Select-control {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.Select-input {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the Solution..

Answer (score -1):

```
.Select-input > input {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.Select--multi .Select-input {
    display: block !important;
}

.Select--multi .Select-multi-value-wrapper {
    display: block !important;
}
```

This is the proper solution in this case. It's working fine.

Comment: `!important` in CSS is the red flag for me. It means something went completely wrong.